# How to store/set data to an external variable from a subscribe and read it again from an other class in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an http response that return some data, i want to store that data in an external variable and read it again from an external class,

```
myExternalVar: any
loadData(id: string) {
  merge()
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.myService!.getData(id);
      }),
      map(data => {
        return data;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return observableOf([]);
      })
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.myExternalVar = data
    });
}
```

so, what am try to do is to call myExternalVar from an other class

Comment: Is `merge()` that http request?

Comment: And what seems to be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.service.ts

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

private data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
data: Observable<any> = this.data$.asObservable();

setData(newData: any){
    this.data$.next(newData);
}
```

in your class where you wrote your function

```
constructor(...data service...) { }

loadData(id: string) {
  merge()
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.myService!.getData(id);
      }),
      map(data => {
        return data;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        this.dataService.setData(observableOf([]));
        return observableOf([]);
      })
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataService.setData(data);
    });
}
```

in somewhere you want to reach your myExternalVar

```
constructor(...data service...) { }

this.dataService.data.subscribe(myExternalVar => {
   ... do something here...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but i did not get this one ( arrSurec$) what it stand for ?

Comment: Hahahaha. I copied it from my project. :) Edited. Sorry for it.

Answer (score 0):

create a service class and inside subscribing block set the value of the service class variable with returned data so that you need to inject the service class inside your custom class to get the data.